# Can't find class TableAdapterManager in visual studio express 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, hierarchical

I tried to use this code

```
 Dim Manager1 As New TableAdapterManager()
```

But it's seem to can't find  TableAdapterManager.

Is this class not supported for visual studio express 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you use a table adapter manager. It is part of a typed `DataSet` and, just like everything else in a typed `DataSet`, it gets generated by VS when you create a Data Source.

Use the Data Sources window in VS to create a new Data Source and specify that you want to create a `DataSet` for your database.  That will generate a typed `DataSet` including a typed `DataTable` for each table in the database.  There will also be a table adapter for each `DataTable` and a table adapter manager that allows you to save changes using multiple table adapters at once.

You can drag those items from the Toolbox to your form in the designer or you can create them in code.  If you create them in code, there will be a namespace dedicated to the table adapters of your `DataSet` so you must either qualify the type names with that namespace or else import it, just like any other namespace.

Comment: I get it. But when i do that, access file's location is fixed. Is there anyway archieve it  with code. I mean because I done with save button (update, insert, remove record by command INSERT pla pla...) for 1 table without relationship. But when I save for related table, I find this way TableAdapterManager(). I don't know is there any way save hierarchical without create dataset on dataset window

Comment: Whether or not you're right depends on what you mean by "fixed" but it doesn't matter anyway. You should have added your Access data file to your project so it should be in the project folder. There's no good reason for it to be anywhere else so the fact that the source file path is fixed is of no consequence. As for after deployment, you can put the data file anywhere you want.  The connection string is stored in the application config file so, if you want the file in other than the default location, you simply edit that config file.

Comment: That said, if you don't want to use a typed `DataSet` then don't.  It's just a convenience. The typed `DataSet` class inherits the standard `DataSet` class, the typed `DataTable` classes inherit the standard `DataTable` class and the table adapters are all wrappers for data adapters.  You can use all those standard classes yourself.  The table adapter manager class simply calls multiple table adapter methods that you can call yourself even if you are using a typed `DataSet`. If you're not, just call methods on data adapters. In short, learn about ADO.NET.

Comment: Thanks for your instruction. This is really helpful for me and I am extremlly appreciate about this. I tried use with The typed dataset but I face to some other problems . Beside that, I coded for user open file exist by openfiledialog and I don't want use the typed dataset now. But I think it will a great idea to use some available methods (TableAdapterManager), maybe I will do it after :))

Comment: By the way, to update related tables, is there any way except use the typed dataset? I search on google and someone said that I need to update cascade. what doesn't it mean? I tried to update for all of records of child table first and then update for all of records in parent table but it get the same error

Comment: If you have new questions then please post them in new threads with all the information specifically relevant to that question. Keep in mind though, we are not here to teach you how to program. If you want to learn how to use ADO.NET then do the appropriate research and learn. When you try to put it into practice and encounter a specific issue, that is when you should post here.